# change json format generated from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and want to convert it to json format.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [5,6,7,8]})
df.to_json()

'{"A":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4},"B":{"0":5,"1":6,"2":7,"3":8}}'
```

The json string I need is like below:

```
'{"A":[1,2,3,4], "B":[5,6,7,8]}'
```

How can I get this json string from pandas dataframe?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient='list'` and consider the string representation of the output.

```
>>> str(df.to_dict(orient='list'))
"{'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to put the argument index=False:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

index:bool, default True
Whether to include the index values in the JSON string. Not including the index (index=False) is only supported when orient is ‘split’ or ‘table’.

New in version 0.23.0.